# PCI-X RAID controllers compatible with Intel X25 SSDs

Tags: intel, pci, raid-controller

Is there any compatibility list published for Intel X25-E/M SSDs and various RAID controllers?  In particular, I am looking to retrofit some Intel X25s to an XW9300, so I need to find a PCI-X SAS/SATA RAID controller (e.g. Adaptec ASR-4800) that will play nicely with these disks.

Alternatively, is anyone aware of any decent guide or reference for compatibility with these disks?  If not, links to reviews or other articles that list the hardware configuration in enough detail to infer what hardware is being used might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3ware 9550SXU-8LP should work, but there is no special requirement for most SSDs, so if you can put a regular SATA-II mechanical HDD in it, you can put a SATA-II SSD in it.

Intel SSDs do not have TRIM support, and they don't really need it anyway, since they perform very well even after extended use, so even if you had a controller with TRIM support, it would not matter.

Comment: Intel released a new firmware to battle with the fragmentation "issues" they have been having. Trim is on the way too so they say.